# How to maintain driver positive values

Tags: drivers

I have an **empty** object driving a **cylinder (X) Rotation** by **empty (Y) Location**. Is there any way to maintain **Cylinder (X) Rotation** on positive values even if I move the **empty (Y) Location** to negative values?

Comment: Do transformation constraints (the little chain link icon tab) do what you want?  I'm not able to check right now but I believe they override driven values in precedence.

Comment: I already tried transformation constraint but as long as I moved the empty to negative direction, the cylinder also rotates on negative X rotation

Answer (score 3):

Yes, though you may need to change the driver to a scripted expression (easy to do). See [The Blender Documentation](http://docs.blender.org) for more info.

I’m guessing you copy-pasted the driver.

1. Right-click the driven property (purple) and click *edit driver*.
2. In the appearing dialogue, change the mode from *averaged sum* to *scripted expression*.
3. Put an `abs(...)` around the variable now in the scripted expression field to take its absolute value. For example, if the variable was `position` the code should be `abs(position)`.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @GeovanieOrcullo If you wanted to constrain the value to some other range you could use the `min()` and `max()` functions instead of `abs()`.